# How to bind Selected Items in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am using `WPF`, `MVVM` and `DevExpress` `GridControl`. There are two panels in my MainWindow.xaml. Panle1 has Grid and Panel2 has `Textbox`. I want that  if i select an item from Grid in Panel1 it's name should display in that Panle2 Textbox. Iwrote Code but it is not working. Can you Please help me to solve this?

*In NameModel From Models Folder I wrote:***

```
private NameModelClass _selectedCustomer;
public NameModelClass SelectedCustomer
{
    get { return _selectedCustomer; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedCustomer != value)
        {
            _selectedCustomer = value;
            LastName = value.LastName;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
        }
     }

    public List<Namess> ListPerson { get; set; }

    void CreateList()
    {
        ListPerson = new List<Namess>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ListPerson.Add(new Namess(i));
        }
    }

    public class Namess
    {
        public Namess(int i)
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName" + i;
            LastName = "LastName" + i;
            Age = i * 10;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***In MianWindow.xaml I wrote:***

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Grid" Caption="Panel1" x:Name="abc1">
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" Height="233" ItemsSource="{Binding ListPerson}" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNames}">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>

<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Panel2" x:Name="abc1">
    <TextBox Width="166" Background="White" Height="33"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

I am new to `MVVM` and c#. I f my query is not clear to you please ask me. Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? There are couple of things wrong with your code, one of which is you binding properties are not calling the `OnPropertyChanged` (`FirstName` and `LastName`). `ListPerson` should also be an `ObservableCollection` not a regular list. Check your output window for any binding errors.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange i want to show selected item from grid in textbox in Panel2

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
private Namess _selectedCustomer;
public Namess SelectedCustomer
{
    get { return _selectedCustomer; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedCustomer != value)
        {
            _selectedCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
        }
     }

    public List<Namess> ListPerson { get; set; }

    void CreateList()
    {
        ListPerson = new List<Namess>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ListPerson.Add(new Namess(i));
        }
    }

    public class Namess : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public Namess(int i)
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName" + i;
            LastName = "LastName" + i;
            Age = i * 10;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value==_lastName)
                    return;
                _lastName=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and in your view:

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Grid" Caption="Panel1" x:Name="abc1">
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" Height="233" ItemsSource="{Binding ListPerson}" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNames,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>

<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Panel2" x:Name="abc1">
    <TextBox Width="166" Background="White" Height="33"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Text="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer.LastName,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

Bsically I changed the type of SelectedCustomer to one of the collection of items. In the view you can set the binding of your TextBox directly to a property of the SelectedCustomer.

Comment: Setting SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" and SelectionMode="Row" on the GridControl worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNames, Mode=TwoWay}"

After looking at it more, your main Namess Class could do with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

With each property raising the property changed event when it *ahem* changes.

Also using an observable collection so when you add and remove items it also raises changes.

That way, the notification change system receives the notify of property changes to change the view accordingly via bindings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to raise the INPC (INotifyPropertyChanged) event for the "LastName" string.

So try this (changed is in the setter below):

```
public NameModelClass SelectedCustomer
    {
    get { return _selectedCustomer; }
    set
        {
        if (_selectedCustomer != value)
            {
            _selectedCustomer = value;
            LastName = value.LastName;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");   //<-- new 
            }
        }
    }
```

You have to send out INPCs so that the binding knows to update to the new value. The displayed binding won't "grab" the new value for LastName unles you raise that event.

Comment: Yes what? did you add the new line? Also, I highly suggest not working with third party controls as a beginner.

Comment: oh sorry ! i mean i have updated my code with this provided code lines by you. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah. Your `SelectedItem` needs to be bound to "SelectedCustomer" not "SelectedNames."

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the "LastName" property getter and see what value (if any) it picks up after selecting one of the customer names from the grid. That's the only thing that is going to give you any information right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36283/discussion-between-spacerach-and-zoya-sheikh)